# filtering data in dataframe based on a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Need to filter the data in dataframe and create a single row out of it. I tried to group by but want different values to filter so am failed to do so. Here is the example

```
#1      #2      #3      #4
1       Bob     10      Eng
2       Jack    21      Tel
3       Rian    11      Tam
4       Vick    10      Ram
5       Jick    20      Mar
6       Rams    10      Mal
7       Venk    21      Mar
```

First need to filter the rows on column #3 as 10 and followed by 21 means

```
#1      #2      #3      #4
1       Bob     10      Eng
2       Jack    21      Tel
3       Rams    10      Mal
4       Venk    21      Mal
```

Then convert this 2 row data into a single row like below

```
#1      #2      #3      #4      #5
1       Bob     Jack    Eng     Tel
2       Jick    Venk    Mal     Mar
```

Being a beginner i tried grouping in several ways but the values need to be picked is in order first row should contain 10 and the immediate row should be 21.

Can anybody suggest which API in pandas will help me achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean by something like?

```
>>> x = df.loc[(df['#3'].eq(10) & df['#3'].shift(-1).eq(21)) | (df['#3'].shift().eq(10) & df['#3'].eq(21))]
>>> x.groupby(np.arange(len(x)) // 2).apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.drop(["#1", "#3"], axis=1).to_numpy().flatten()).T).reset_index(drop=True).rename(lambda x: f'#{x + 1}', axis=1)
     #1   #2    #3   #4
0   Bob  Eng  Jack  Tel
1  Rams  Mal  Venk  Mar
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
mask = df["#3"].eq(21) & df["#3"].shift().eq(10)
mask = mask.shift(-1).fillna(False) | mask
x = (
    df[mask]
    .groupby(np.arange(mask.sum()) // 2)
    .apply(lambda x: list(x["#2"]) + list(x["#4"]))
).apply(pd.Series)
x.columns = [f"#{x+2}" for x in x.columns]
x = x.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "#1"})
x["#1"] += 1
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   #1    #2    #3   #4   #5
0   1   Bob  Jack  Eng  Tel
1   2  Rams  Venk  Mal  Mar
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists are ordered iterables, and the `filter` generator reads each item in, one at a time in that order. Therefore, it will yield output in order.

The `filter` function takes boolean value as input.

```
list(filter(lambda a: a is 10 or a is 21, col_3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `21` always comes just after `10`, you may like:

```
df_shifted = df.shift(-1, axis=0)  # df is the original DataFrame you have.
is_ok = (df["#3"] == 10) & (df_shifted["#3"] == 21)
ans = pd.concat([df[is_ok], df_shifted[is_ok]], axis=1).drop(columns="#3")
```

This will return:

```
  #2   #4  #2   #4
1 Bob  Eng Jack Tel
6 Rams Mal Venk Mar
```

Comment: It will not come always. We may have only 10 or 21 or 10 after 21. All these are invalid. only combination which is valid is 21 after 10.

Comment: The way in my answer will behave as you want. It will ignore single 10 or 21 as well as 10 after 21. By "just" I meant that my code cannot find patterns like [10, 1, 21], where something is inserted between 10 and 21.

Comment: Anyway it seems most of the other answers are based on the same filtering strategy as in mine. You can choose the one you like.